# Nginx Location Regex for keycloak

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I have a keycloak, react web and a spring boot app are living behind nginx.
The frontend (react) and the backend (spring boot) are calling the keycloak service over the nginx proxy at the flowing urls:

- `realms/.../..etc`
- `admin/.../..etc`
- `js/.../.../..etc`
- `resources/.../...etc`

All those urls are reverse proxing to:

`Http://keylock:8180`

I don't want to implements multiple locations in nginx for all those urls!

I am thinking about url rewriting to

- `auth/realms/...`
- `auth/dmin/..`
  ...

Or another clean solution with regex, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) module for this.

```
location /auth {
    rewrite ^/auth(/|$)(.*) /$2/ break;
    proxy_pass    http://keylock:8180;
}
```

In fact, with this method, I get the second part of the url and proxy it.

For example, when request send to `/auth/realms/...` the url rewrite to `/realms/...` and send it to keycloak `http://keylock:8180/realms/...`

Comment: `proxy_pass` can handle this without `rewrite`: `location /auth/ { proxy_pass http://keylock:8180/; }` (notice the slashes)

Comment: @Roman you are right. Thank you I learned something new from you.

Comment: Thank you!  But the Problem with this solution is, that the keycloak Admin Page are called like this:  http://keycloak:port/admin and  not http://keycloak:port/auth/admin

Comment: can i use something like this:

`location  ~ /(realms|js|resources|admin)/$ {
proxy_pass    http://keylock:8180;
}`

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
    location  ~ ^/(realms|js|resources|admin)/ {
    proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://keycloak;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```